# Write to file in binary on a microcontroller

Tags: c, embedded, fatfs

I'm using a STM32476 Nucleo board, and right now I write some data from sensors in a readable file, but it's way too slow. To show some code of what I'm doing now:

```
static char buffer[LINE_MAX];
char* p = buffer;
p += sprintf(p, "%f,%f,%f,", s.ax.val, s.ay.val, s.az.val);
p += sprintf(p, "%f,%f,%f,", s.gx.val, s.gy.val, s.gz.val);
p += sprintf(p, " %f"DEGREE_UTF8"C\r\n", s.temperature);

int ret;

unsigned bytes_written=0;
if ((ret = f_write(&USERFile, buffer, length, &bytes_written)) != FR_OK || bytes_written != length) {
    hang("write failed: %d (written = %u)", ret, bytes_written);
}
```

How could I change this to write in binary instead?

Comment: `f_write` is a function from which library? How do you know what's the bottleneck? Does this board run a GNU/Linux kernel? What is the filesystem?

Comment: Most likely this is FatFS library (for FAT32 filesystem), and on freestanding environment (no linux or similar).

Comment: Yes im using fatfs library and FreeRTOS .
Its in different tasks, and for the sampling of data on 200 hz the queue for the task to write data on the sd card is getting full

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the most simplest form you just dump the data as is:

```
float data = ...
fwrite(&file, &data, sizeof data, &written);
```

This of course doesn't handle endianness gracefully, and doesn't have any structure (you might want to look at more sophisticated formats for that, like CBOR).

If I remember correctly, FatFS already does some buffering behind the scenes, but it could also be faster to `memcpy` all data to temporary buffer first and then write that. You need to experiment, if speed is your top priority.